# Prevent recursive function from causing an "out of bounds" error

Tags: java

I have been working on a program to count vowels in inputted text. It uses this method to recursively add to a vowel count every time a vowel is found. However, I get an out of bounds error every time `lastPos` reaches negative 1. How can I get this to stop once `lastPos` reaches -1?

```
static int R_countVowels(String s, int lastPos) 
{           
    switch (s.charAt(lastPos))
    {  case 'a': case 'A':
       case 'e': case 'E':
       case 'i': case 'I':
       case 'o': case 'O':
       case 'u': case 'U': return (1 + R_countVowels(s, --lastPos));
       default: return R_countVowels(s, --lastPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: By adding some code that checks the value of `lastPos`...

Comment: If this is homework, please add the "homework" tag to your question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming this is homework so no code.

Recursive functions require a [base case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Description).  You need to define your base case to return 0 (no vowels) for an empty input and check for the base case before your inductive step (recursive call).

Answer (score 0):

Insert an `if` before the `switch()`:

```
if (lastpos < 0) {
  // stop the recursion
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I just used return 0; to stop it.

Comment: Not enough, still can throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`